# C++ min function comparison with scalar value

Tags: c++

I have if statement like this.

```
typedef float Scalar;

// ...

if ( someScalarValue > std::numeric_limits<Scalar>::min() )
{
...
}
```

This produces error:

> E0040 expected an identifier

Probably because min asks values.

But I have a code of somebody else in application that this does not produce error. Why this if statement could even work? And how to make it work for me?

Comment: What is `Scalar`? Is there a template specialization of `std::numeric_limits` available for it?

Comment: typedef float Scalar;

Comment: What's the type of `SomeScalarValue`?

Comment: Scalar is float with some functions inside

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, you're compiling this on MSVC. `windows.h` defined `max` and `min`, and hence this breaks `std::numeric_limits`. Try to add `#define NOMINMAX` before including `windows.h` or globally, or add `#undef min` before using `numeric_limits`.

Also, `Scalar` must be numerical type (like `typedef unsigned Scalar`)

Comment: Or do the sane thing which avoids the preprocessor, and use parentheses around the id which has `min`, like `(std::numeric_limits<Scalar>::min)`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I (std::numeric_limits<Scalar>::min) I have to compare value with float, do you have any ideas how to convert that scalar value to float, simple (float) cast does not work...

Comment: @Petras What is `Scalar`?

Comment: Scalar is float